# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll problem with Mono compiler

Tags: c#, mono, azure

When trying to compile a solution that contains a project with a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll using the Mono compiler it fails. Why? (Google-ing provides no suitable, quick answer for this question currently).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the error message coming out of Hudson:

```
error CS0011: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableQuery`1[TElement]' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Comment: Do you get some sort of error message?

Comment: Updated with the error message from Hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume (based on my experience) that this is tied to the fact that ths storage client references the WCF data services client (System.Data.Client) which isn't avaialble/working on Mono. I've done some work on attempting to get it to compile/work on Mono, but have yet to succeed. You might have more luck than I... source is available at http://odata.codeplex.com (HT @dunnry)